# Like more than one facebook page at the same time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page

Is there any way to like more than one page at the same time on facebook?
For example the user may have a list of pages with checkbuttons attached and when a button is pressed, all pages that are checked should get a like. Is that possible?

Comment: @Martey Why I think it can not be seen as a duplicate is because what I need is to do this for more pages. The user might have 100 pages and wants to just press a button and like them all. For example an advertising company might have been paid to like and share 100 pages, they would have an json document with the pages to be liked and shared and would just want to press a single button to do this all rather than doing it for each page

Comment: There is literally no possible reason you'd want to do that that is compliant with facebook's policies; plus, the question martey linked is the definitive answer - if you wanted to like multiple pages you could use a `for` loop, at least until the anti spam systems catch you

Comment: @lgy Wouldn't be spamming, it was just an example of use, it's not what I actually want to do. Also even with the example, it would not be spam, because the user would be able to limit and choose what to appear on the screen. If what promoting companies are doing now is legal, why doing it faster would be illegal? The idea is not of sending a bunch of people links, rather if you have a lot of links, like them all automatically instead of going on each of them and pressing the like button

Comment: Paying companies to Like or share your pages is in violation of Facebook's Platform Policies - see Section IV-4 - https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: @Martey alright, thank you for the info. Anyway the topic doesn't deserve debate, because it's not what I need to do. It was just a spontaneous example of use that came in my mind. Thank you for the question link, it was useful :)